# Build sum of array based on index array

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

I have three arrays

```
A = array([0, 0, 0, 0])

B = array([0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1])

C = array([0, 0, 1, 2])
```

I want to assign to every element i of array A the sum of all elements of array B for which array C points to i. The result should be

```
A = array([0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 0])
```

So far I get the desired result as follows:

```
for i in np.unique(C):
 A[i] = np.sum(B[C==i])
```

The arrays are large, and the loop is slow. I am trying to accomplish this without a loop, but I don't know how. Thank you for suggestions!

Comment: As an example of the linked answer, you could do `np.add.at(A,C,B)` to get `array([ 0.7,  0.2,  0.1,  0. ])`-- make sure that A has a float dtype though!

Comment: Thank you for the hint, that is exactly what I was looking for.